# How do I add the places plugin in the mapbox navigation app (android)?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mapbox, mapbox-android

I've created a turn-by-turn navigation application using mapbox and I wanted to add in the search bar in the application as well. I read forums online and came to know about the places plugin. I have added the required dependencies but am unsure how to go about actually adding the plugin into the application. I'm a newbie and would really appreciate help/guide of sorts.

This is what I've done so far.

This is my Main Activity:

```
package com.example.mapbox_with_search_bar;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.mapbox.android.core.location.LocationEngine;
import com.mapbox.android.core.location.LocationEngineListener;
import com.mapbox.android.core.location.LocationEnginePriority;
import com.mapbox.android.core.location.LocationEngineProvider;
import com.mapbox.android.core.permissions.PermissionsListener;
import com.mapbox.android.core.permissions.PermissionsManager;
import com.mapbox.api.directions.v5.models.DirectionsResponse;
import com.mapbox.api.directions.v5.models.DirectionsRoute;
import com.mapbox.geojson.Point;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.Mapbox;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.annotations.Marker;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.annotations.MarkerOptions;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.camera.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.geometry.LatLng;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapboxMap;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.plugins.locationlayer.LocationLayerPlugin;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.plugins.locationlayer.modes.CameraMode;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.plugins.locationlayer.modes.RenderMode;
import com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.ui.v5.NavigationLauncher;
import com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.ui.v5.NavigationLauncherOptions;
import com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.ui.v5.route.NavigationMapRoute;
import com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.v5.navigation.NavigationRoute;

import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, LocationEngineListener, PermissionsListener, MapboxMap.OnMapClickListener
{
    private MapView mapView;
    private MapboxMap map;
    private PermissionsManager permissionsManager;
    private LocationEngine locationEngine;
    private LocationLayerPlugin locationLayerPlugin;
    private Location originLocation;
    private Point originPosition;
    private Point destinationPosition;
    private DirectionsRoute currentRoute;
    private Marker destinationMarker;
    private LatLng originCoord;
    private LatLng destinationCoord;
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private NavigationMapRoute navigationMapRoute;
    private Button startButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Mapbox.getInstance(this,getString(R.string.access_token));
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mapView = findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mapView.getMapAsync(this);
    }

//    MADE CHANGES HERE
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(MapboxMap mapboxMap)
    {
        this.map = mapboxMap;
        enableLocationPlugin();
        originCoord = new LatLng(originLocation.getLatitude(), originLocation.getLongitude());
        map.addOnMapClickListener(this);
        startButton = findViewById(R.id.startButton);
        startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                NavigationLauncherOptions options = NavigationLauncherOptions.builder()
                        .directionsRoute(currentRoute)
                        .shouldSimulateRoute(true)
                        .build();
                NavigationLauncher.startNavigation(MainActivity.this, options);
            }
        });
    }

    private void enableLocationPlugin()
    {
        if (PermissionsManager.areLocationPermissionsGranted(this))
        {
            initializeLocationEngine();
            locationLayerPlugin = new LocationLayerPlugin(mapView, map);
            locationLayerPlugin.setLocationLayerEnabled(true);
            locationLayerPlugin.setCameraMode(CameraMode.TRACKING);
            getLifecycle().addObserver(locationLayerPlugin);
            locationLayerPlugin.setRenderMode(RenderMode.NORMAL);
        }
        else
        {
            permissionsManager = new PermissionsManager(this);
            permissionsManager.requestLocationPermissions(this);
        }
    }

    private void setCameraPosition(Location location)
    {
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude()),15.0));
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapClick(@NonNull LatLng point)
    {
        if (destinationMarker != null)
        {
            map.removeMarker(destinationMarker);
        }
        destinationCoord = point;
        destinationMarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(destinationCoord));
        destinationPosition = Point.fromLngLat(destinationCoord.getLongitude(), destinationCoord.getLatitude());
        originPosition = Point.fromLngLat(originCoord.getLongitude(), originCoord.getLatitude());
        getRoute(originPosition, destinationPosition);
        startButton.setEnabled(true);
        startButton.setBackgroundResource(R.color.mapboxBlue);
    }

    private void getRoute(Point origin, Point destination)
    {
        NavigationRoute.builder(this)
                .accessToken(Mapbox.getAccessToken())
                .origin(origin)
                .destination(destination)
                .build()
                .getRoute(new Callback<DirectionsResponse>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<DirectionsResponse> call, Response<DirectionsResponse> response)
                    {
                        // You can get the generic HTTP info about the response
                        Log.d(TAG, "Response code: " + response.code());
                        if (response.body() == null)
                        {
                            Log.e(TAG, "No routes found, make sure you set the right user and access token.");
                            return;
                        }
                        else if (response.body().routes().size() < 1)
                        {
                            Log.e(TAG, "No routes found");
                            return;
                        }

                        currentRoute = response.body().routes().get(0);

                        // Draw the route on the map
                        if (navigationMapRoute != null)
                        {
                            navigationMapRoute.removeRoute();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            navigationMapRoute = new NavigationMapRoute(null, mapView, map, R.style.NavigationMapRoute);
                        }
                        navigationMapRoute.addRoute(currentRoute);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<DirectionsResponse> call, Throwable throwable)
                    {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + throwable.getMessage());
                    }
                });
    }

    private void initializeLocationEngine()
    {
        LocationEngineProvider locationEngineProvider = new LocationEngineProvider(this);
        locationEngine = locationEngineProvider.obtainBestLocationEngineAvailable();
        locationEngine.setPriority(LocationEnginePriority.HIGH_ACCURACY);
        locationEngine.activate();

        @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
        Location lastLocation = locationEngine.getLastLocation();
        if (lastLocation != null)
        {
            originLocation = lastLocation;
        }
        else
        {
            locationEngine.addLocationEngineListener(this);
        }

    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    @Override
    public void onConnected()
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void onExplanationNeeded(List<String> permissionsToExplain)
    {
        //present toast
    }

    @Override
    public void onPermissionResult(boolean granted)
    {
        if (granted)
        {
            enableLocationPlugin();
        }
        else
        {
            //Toast.makeText(this, R.string.user_location_permission_not_granted, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults)
    {
        permissionsManager.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    @Override
    protected void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();
        mapView.onStart();
        if (locationLayerPlugin != null)
        {
            locationLayerPlugin.onStart();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        mapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        mapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop()
    {
        super.onStop();
        mapView.onStop();
        if (locationLayerPlugin != null)
        {
            locationLayerPlugin.onStart();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState)
    {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory()
    {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mapView.onLowMemory();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        mapView.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

This is my project level gradle file:

```
buildscript
{
    repositories
    {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    }
    dependencies
    {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects
{
    repositories
    {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven
        {
            url 'https://mapbox.bintray.com/mapbox'
        }
    }

}
```

This is the app level build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android
{
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig
    {
        applicationId "com.example.kushagravashisht.mapbox_with_search_bar"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes
    {
        release
        {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions
    {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies
{
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    // MAPBOX DEPENDENCIES
    implementation ('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:6.5.0@aar')
    {
        transitive=true
    }
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation:0.20.0'
    implementation ('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation-ui:0.20.0')
    {
        transitive = true
    }
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
    // PLUGIN-PLACES DEPENDENCIES
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-places:0.6.0'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-places:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

Please let me know if anything else is required from the code. Would really appreciate if anyone could help me with integrating the plugin-places in this existing application.

Comment: Did you look at the example app in the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-plugins-android/tree/master/plugin-places)?

Comment: I did but couldn't integrate that into my project, unfortunately. Do you have a project I can have a look at?

Comment: I haven't used the Places plugin myself but if you update your question to include the specific issue you're having integrating it with your project, I or someone else may be able to help.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Matt. Updating the question now. Hopefully someone can help me out now :p

Answer (score 2):

[This example](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-plugins-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/plugins/testapp/activity/places/AutocompleteFragmentActivity.kt) may be able to help here.  The `PlaceAutocompleteFragement` needs to be added to your `FragmentManager` like:

```
        val placeOptions = PlaceOptions.builder()
                .toolbarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary))
                .hint("Begin searching...")
                .build()

        autocompleteFragment = PlaceAutocompleteFragment.newInstance(
                Mapbox.getAccessToken() ?: throw MapboxConfigurationException(),
                placeOptions
        )

        val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, autocompleteFragment, PlaceAutocompleteFragment.TAG)
        transaction.commit()
```

`R.id.fragment_container` is important here because that determines where your fragment will show within your layout.

To detect that someone has clicked a "Place" `CarmenFeature`, you can add a click listener like:

```
    autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(object : PlaceSelectionListener {
        override fun onPlaceSelected(carmenFeature: CarmenFeature) {
            Toast.makeText(this@AutocompleteFragmentActivity,
                    carmenFeature.text(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            finish()
        }

        override fun onCancel() {
            finish()
        }
    })
```

Hope this helps a bit, thanks for checking out our SDKs!